# Regex pattern version and name

Tags: regex, artifactory

I am using Artifactory rest api via python script to perform searches on file names with personal branches so I can delete them.

The pattern file name is `artifactory-version_number-personalbranchname.zip`
version_number has nunber followed by dots ie `1.0.0` or `1.10.196`
`<personalbranchname>` is a strong with dev’s use name.

I do want it delete file name with just version ie `artifactory-version_number.zip`

Artifactory search pattern supports `*` and `?` But thinking that is not enough so I probably need to use the regex in python to match the pattern which I am looking to get some help on

Comment: You should provide several examples of these filenames and the expected result. Overall, `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*` would allow you target a version number.

Comment: Example:
match ->artifactname-1.0.0-myname.1.tgz but do not match artifactname-1.0.0-.123.tgz